# Setting config values with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have the following code:

```
#Set the .config settings
$appSettings = (Get-AzureWebsite -Name $webAppName -Slot $SlotName).AppSettings
$conStrings = (Get-AzureWebsite -Name $webAppName -Slot $SlotName).ConnectionStrings    

$xmlDocument = New-Object XML
$path = (Get-ChildItem -Path ${location} -Filter "*.exe.config" -Recurse).Fullname
$xmlDocument.Load($path)

foreach($setting in $XmlDocument.configuration.appSettings.ChildNodes)
{
  $setting.Value = $appSettings[$setting.Key].Value
}

$xmlDocument.Save($path)
```

and I get the following error when I run this (context is Octopus)

```
Invoke-Expression : Cannot set "value" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties.
```

I can't seem to figure this out as I was expecting the Value to be a string. I am trying to set the values in the xml to be the same as those from the Azure dashboard appsettings (and config strings) but I just cannot get this to work.

How do I correctly set each of the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me in the end:

```
#Set the .config settings
$appSettings = (Get-AzureWebsite -Name $webAppName -Slot $SlotName).AppSettings
$conStrings = (Get-AzureWebsite -Name $webAppName -Slot $SlotName).ConnectionStrings

#Load xml config file
$xmlDocument = New-Object XML
$path = (Get-ChildItem -Path ${location} -Filter "*.exe.config" -Recurse).Fullname
$xmlDocument.Load($path)

#Update settings from appSettings
foreach($setting in $appSettings.GetEnumerator())
{

    $targetNode = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key='$($setting.Name)']")
    if($targetNode -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host "Target: $($targetNode.Key) being set to $($setting.Value)"
        $targetNode.Value = $setting.Value
    }   
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Target Node was null"
        Write-Host "Setting was Key: $($setting.Name) Value: $($setting.Value)"
    }
}

#Update connection string section
foreach($setting in $conStrings.GetEnumerator())
{
    $targetNode = $XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='$($setting.Name)']")
    if($targetNode -ne $null)
    {
        Write-Host "Target: $($targetNode.Name) being set to $($setting.connectionString)"
        $targetNode.connectionString = $($setting.connectionString)
    }   
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Target Node was null"
        Write-Host "Setting was Key: $($setting.Name) Value: $($setting.connectionString)"
    }
}

$xmlDocument.Save($path)
```

I am fairly new to Powershell and I must have made every mistake going while doing this but it is done now and I have learned something useful. \0/